# Why did Jesus leave?

Tags: life-of-jesus, biblical-basis, ascension

With ascension day coming up so quickly, I have a question:

According to the Bible, why did Jesus leave? I've read some ideas but few have any actual Biblical backing. Could anyone point me in the direction of this?

Comment: To sit at the right of God.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bible is pretty clear.

> **[John 16:7 (NLT)](http://bible.cc/john/16-7.htm)**
>
> But in fact, it is best for you that I go away, because if I don't,
> the Advocate won't come. If I do go away, then I will send him to you.

Jesus left so that the Holy Spirit would come.

Comment: Here's another passage to expand on that. John 7:38-39.